# How to set memory limit to NodeJS running with forever

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm running my **Node JS** process through **forever** as below:

> sudo forever start -o out.log -e error.log myServer.js

I want to change the **memory limit** of my NodeJs server as I do like below when I'm running it purely with node.

> node --max-old-space-size=512 myServer.js

How I can do the same when I'm running it with forever? Is there some way like 'forever start --max-old-space-size=512'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass node options by changing the command (which defaults to "node").

So for example:

```
sudo forever start -c "node --max_old_space_size=512" -o out.log -e error.log myServer.js
```

Comment: The parameter name, at least for Node v6.9.4 is "--max_old_space_size".  With underscores. This can be checked with "node --v8-options".

Comment: And it's `--max-old-space-size` (with dashes) in recent versions of Node.